# Which Knot to Use on Tefillin Shel Rosh

Tags: minhag, tefilin, ashkenazi, mesorah-tradition, tying-knots-kosheir

When I was a child, I saw that all people had the same knot on their Tefillin Shel Rosh - a Double Daled (Ashkenazi community).

Recently [I saw a comment](http://www.tefillin.co.il) that even those who grew up with a Double Daled, and even if their Father's minhag was a Double Daled, that they should all switch to a Single Daled.

My questions are:

1. What are the sources for this, if any?
2. Why is the Single Daled supposed to be "better"?  Is this only for Kabbalistic reasons, or is there a real Halachic reason for this?
3. Are these poskim who require this change in minhag correct to do so?
4. Are there any Ashkenazi Poskim and/or Groups today that specifically say that a Double Daled is preferable?

Comment: I heard that there are detailed instructions for tying the shel rosh knot in [I forget if it was the Tur, the Mechaber, or someone else], and that if you follow them, you get a double daled.

Comment: If you could include (by [edit]ing) where you saw that comment recommending single-dalet, that would be helpful. (It might be a known minority opinion, perhaps. IDK.)

Comment: I know that the Yekkes are still makpid about using a double-dalet knot without the modifications to remove the "cross" inside. As such, this is what I do.

Comment: Also mind if I edit in a question about whether these poskim are correct to require people to change their ancient minhagim?

Comment: I've heard that 3 areas of the shel yad combined with Shel Rosh should spell the word "Shadai" - Shin via the straps bound on your wrist. Yod is the knot on the shel yad, and daled via the knot on the shel rosh. I have a double daled, because the last sofer who inspected my tefillin made it that way, and I'm no "knotter". However, to me this shape looks like the lanyard box stitch that I did in summer camp - nothing like a daled. I like camp, so I leave it that way ;-) But, I guess people who are *makpid* on "Shadai" insist on the single daled.

Comment: @DanF: Caution: I noticed this similarity to the lanyard box stitch, too, and once, when I had occasion to retie my knot for some reason, as a teenager, tied it as if it was that, but then a rabbi noticed that it looked wrong and then showed me that I had missed a loop in the traditional "double daled" knot.

Comment: @IsaacMoses - As I said, I'm no "knotter", so I assume that my sofer did it correctly. (My sofer does "count" for something :-) :-) If you find a link to a video or diagram that shows how to make the knot, please ping.

Comment: @DanF [*Tefillin*](http://www.judaism.com/tefillin/dp/CGIBC/) by [R' Aryeh Kaplan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aryeh_Kaplan) contains step-by-step knot-tying diagrams.

Comment: @IsaacMoses - T.R. ! I'll view this later, b"n

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt: I do not mind if you edit the question to ask if that is correct.

Comment: @DanF: We were also taught as children about (from an Ashkenazi perspective) that the Shin on your hand, the (double) Daled on your Tefilin shel Rosh, and the Yud on the Tefilin shel Yad combine to make "Shadai".  This is reasonable whether or not it is a single or double Daled.

Comment: Here's a partial answer: The MMA madrich gives requires a double-dalet knot http://www.moreshesashkenaz.org/en/guide . Furthermore, there are Sephardim, such as the London community, who also maintain this practice: https://sites.google.com/site/londonsephardiminhag/tephillin . Feel free to convert this to an answer if you wish.

Comment: A related question: If Moshe saw the tefillin knot at the back of Hashem's head, what did he see? Double Daled or Single?  ;-)

Comment: @IsaacMoses It's the Beit Yosef (end of OC 32) and various Rishonim before him (some quoting Geonim), and they all come out as the double dalet. There's no explicit evidence for a single dalet knot in Rishonim (only references to knots which look "like" a dalet, which is far from conclusive).

Comment: @isaac btw it could be that what you teacher showed you was actually a variation on the traditional double dalet knot made in some Christian countries to avoid having the shape of a cross on the back.

Comment: @DoubleAA Very interesting. Can you point to a reference on this?

Comment: @isaac beit yosef above....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @NoachmiFrankfurt mentioned above, and suggested I convert into an answer:

Here's a partial answer: The MMA madrich gives requires a double-dalet knot http://www.moreshesashkenaz.org/en/guide.

Furthermore, there are Sephardim, such as the London community, who also maintain this practice: https://sites.google.com/site/londonsephardiminhag/tephillin

Answer (score 2):

Rav Shachter has said (and written in Nefesh HaRav) that Rav Soloveitchik consistently advised students to follow their father's minhagim, with two exceptions: (a) eating in the sukkah on shmini atzeret, and (b) the shape of the knot in the tefillin shel rosh, where he thought that the alternative view (i.e., not eating in the sukkah and the double dalet) was mistaken.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for the answer. Just to clarify, Rav Schachter in the name of Rav Soloveitchik said not to use double-dalet? The sentence structure is a bit confusing to me.

Comment: @user9162:  Really?  There is a lecture on yutorah.org on Minhagim where the Rabbi specifically mentions what you say above, that the minhag to not eat in the Sukkah on Shemini Atzeret in Chutz L'Aretz in an invalid minhag that should be changed.  But the Rabbi says nothing about Double-Daled Tefillin.

Comment: I found the lecture on yutorah.  It is Rabbi Lebowitz  (http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/752247/Rabbi_Aryeh_Lebowitz/Ten_Minute_Halacha_-_Minhagim) where Rabbi Lebowitz specifically only talks about Shemini Atzeret

Comment: @Ask613, perhaps Rabbi Lebowitz only mentioned that one, but [here](http://www.aishdas.org/avodah/vol01/v01n035.shtml#02) are some [confirmations](http://www.torahmusings.com/2011/11/the-ravs-siddur-has-arrived/#comment-34583). That first one is even a personal testimonial of someone changing their custom due to it.

Comment: What was R' Soloveitchik's source for his p'sak?

Comment: @Yishai:  Interesting, although I still wonder what the sources are for all this.  And actually I once davened with Rabbi Meir Soloveichik, and he had a double-daled on his Tefilin.  I asked him about it, and he said (a) that he had two pairs of Tefilin, and he thought one had a double on one set of Tefilin, and a single Daled on the other and (b) he did not seem that concerned either way.

Comment: Something else I wonder about: It is well known that the Rav had a Chabad teacher as a kid.  To what extent were his decisions influenced by this?  For example, I am pretty sure that Chabad uses a single Daled.  Is that where his opinion comes from?  We will probably never know, but I do wonder...