# Why has a single daled knot become the "standard" on tefillin?

Tags: minhag, tefilin, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, ashkenazi, tying-knots-kosheir

It has been brought to my attention that originally, both Ashkenazim and Sephardim used a [square knot](https://www.en.tefillin.co.il/images/Gimages/order/daled.jpg) (also called the "double-daled knot") on the tefillin shel rosh, but when the [daled knot](https://www.en.tefillin.co.il/images/Gimages/order/daledd.jpg) was invented, tefillin makers began tying it in place of the square knot.

It seems that in general, the Ashkenazi custom is to use a square knot, while the Sephardi custom is to use a daled knot. There are, of course, exceptions to this: various Chasidic groups use the daled knot, and certain Sephardi communities use the square knot (such as the London community).

Some have told me that the use of the square knot is obsolete, and that one should use the daled knot, even if his family custom is to use a square. [Some](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/75265/11486) have even cited Rav Soloveitchik in this.

A few questions:

What are the origins of both knots?

Is there a reason why Ashkenazim use a square knot while Sephardim use a daled? Also, considering that Spanish-Portuguese customs usually reflect an older Sephardi tradition, does this mean that the older custom is to use a square knot?

Why would a daled knot be preferred, when it seems the square knot is older?

If you look at companies which sell tefillin online (whether this is a good idea or not aside), the default option is to have a daled. Square knots are usually tied upon special request. Could it be that the daled knot is much easier to tie?

Comment: Single dalet is actually much harder to tie. Yemenites also use double dalet.

Comment: Note there are two different knots known in writing as "double dalet". One of them is nearly entirely not used nowadays but you have to be very careful reading written sources to know which they refer to.

Comment: @DoubleAA I am aware with the fact that there's another "double-daled" knot but it's very strange and almost not used at all. For those who have no idea what we're talking about, it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejSod.png

Comment: Almost not used at all nowadays, but the Mishna Berura quotes an Acharon who wrote very strongly against that double dalet, and if you just read the Mishna Berura's quote you don't realize which double dalet he was talking about. So it's important to have historical context.

Comment: @DoubleAA I've changed the notation to "square knot" and "daled knot" in the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: Every picture of Tefillin-knots from the medieval period has the square knot, and every written instructions for tying the knot from then produces the square knot. (There are obviously Rishonim who don't write instructions and say it looks like a Dalet, but that can't be a proof they held single dalet, since even many square knot rishonim say explicitly it looks like a Dalet.)

Comment: @DoubleAA Alright, I think we can cement the square knot as being older. So now the question remains: when was the daled knot developed, and when did become so popular?

Comment: I'd guess its proponents would tell you it was developed by Moshe/God and it's been popular for millennia.

Comment: See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/57259/5275. I don't have access to any of the links in that answer, now. See if anything there answers your question. If it does, this one **might** be a dupe.

Comment: We all use a square knot - so add about 3 dozen people to your count. ;-)

Comment: Btw for people who claim their family tradition is to use a single dalet, how many of you can trace that back farther than the whims of the Sofer who sold your dad his Tefillin? Remember most people just take what the Sofer gives them and don't ask twice.

Comment: @DoubleAA Like me :) Notice how I said, "I _have_ a daled knot", not, "My family minhag is to use a daled." :)

Comment: I have no proof for this, but to answer your title: probably people in the last few hundred years who didn't know better (which in the details of Safrus unfortunately includes many rabbis) picked the one that looked most like a Dalet because they had read that it's supposed to look like a Dalet. I mean, if you didn't know the history, read about the how the knot should resemble a Dalet, saw the two modern options, and heard what seems like forced explanations for how the square is a Dalet, what would you think?

Comment: Unfortunately this question is worded in a way that makes it very hard to answer. I can give you all the sources where this mistaken Dalet very obviously comes from, and why they are obviously wrong, but I can't prove that those sources are what made it the popular standard.

Comment: _Could it be that the daled knot is much easier to tie?_ No! the square is easier to tie and easier to adjust when the straps stretch after extended use.

Comment: @DoubleAA I found something interesting: the Mishnah Berurah describes the knot on the tefillin shel rosh and based on his description, it _seems_ to me that he's talking about a daled knot, not a square knot. (M.B. 27:37)

Comment: @ezra I don't see how that indicates that. Even in a square knot the right strap comes out downwards and the left strap comes out horizontally

Comment: When I was purchasing tefillin for my son, the sofer told me that the square knot is Yekkish in origin and the dalet knot is litvish?

Answer (score 2):

Your question begins with a misunderstanding; I am sepharadi, and the dalet knot does not exist in our tradition. That custom began in ashkenaz and became standard due to a literal examination of the text. Every sepharadi community is halachically obligated to use a square knot because that's what we have always done. We started using dalet knots when sepharadim moved to the states and israel, and when turning in tefillin to get checked by ashkenazi sopherim it would be returned with dalet knots. Nothing to do with sepharadi custom or obligation. It just took over in the last century because of assimilation and people not caring about preserving their traditions.

Comment: חנן, welcome to Mi Yodeya and thanks for this first answer! One way this site works differently from most sites is that we try to bring sources to back up our answers here. Great to have you learn with us and I hope to see you around! Here'a a quick tour: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887

Comment: Except the original Ashkenazi minhag is to use a square as well. -1

Comment: From my experience I have never met anyone Sephardi that uses square knot except for Yemenites and some (not a majority) Spanish-Portugese.

Comment: Apologies if my answer seemed a little hostile, re-reading I feel that this may have been the case. To clarify, it was also the original ashkenazi minhag to use a square knot. This had confused me before so I asked a number of tefillin makers and they told me the older tradition is a square knot, but the modern proclivity leans toward a daled knot due to it looking more like a daled. When I receive tefillin, I always do two things; redirect the feed of the shel rosh resuot so that the bottom lays on the head, and retie the knot to a square. Square is also easier to adjust, and fits easily IMO